# fetch code from svn on basis of commit

Tags: svn, revision, changeset

Below is the scenario for what I want:

- I have a Feature List that contains different line items to fix. We can number these like line item1,line item2,line item3 up to line itemn
- A team of 3 developer is working on this feature list. Developer A is working on line item1, Developer B is working on line item2, Developer C  is working on line item3
- They are committing their code on SVN in the following order:

  - Developer B is committing line item2
  - Developer C is committing line item3
  - Developer A is committing line item1

Now I want to fetch updates only of line item1 from SVN .

How can we achieve this if changes are made to the common file for all 3 line items?
Does Revision number and change set can help in this? If yes how we can achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is at all possible. As far as I understand the way SVN works, it saves the entire file for each revision. So, for each revision is stores the entire file in its current state. However, if you diff it with the previous revision (assuming developer A committed the last in  line and there were no more commits), it will show you the changes you need.

But this is probably not what you want. The developers will commit one after another, and I'm not aware about the way to obtain a file with changes from developer A only.

Comment: Is this scnerio possible with vault?

Comment: Yan, can you please look on to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513169/how-to-get-partial-update-from-subversion

Comment: is it possible that i mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is not what continuous integration is designed to do.

My understanding of continuous integration is to integrate/build any change to ensure that the project is as up to date as possible and identity any breaking code.

As such you would want each change to be built in turn.

If you want to ensure that one change is integrated/built before another, it sounds like you should consider issuing the work to the developers in that order?